# Pass in an object reference when Deserializing

Tags: c#, serialization

I have an object that is deserialized with this:

```
public object DeSerializeObject(string filename)
        {
            object objectToSerialize;
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            objectToSerialize = (object)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return objectToSerialize;
        }
```

---

```
    public GUI_Settings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        PrinterFont = (Font)info.GetValue("_printFont", typeof(Font));
    }
```

How could I pass in and object as I deserialize it? Kind of like this

```
public object DeSerializeObject(string filename, someObject thing)
            {
                ......
                objectToSerialize = (object)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream, thing);
                .....
            }
```

---

```
public GUI_Settings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt, someObject thing)
        {

            PrinterFont = (Font)info.GetValue("_printFont", typeof(Font));
            _thing = thing;
        }
```

---

I'm not quite sure if I explained it clearly let me try again.

Inside of my main class I say

```
_settings = (GUI_Settings)new ObjectSerializing()
    .DeSerializeObject("Settings.data");
```

or if I understand what Jalal Aldeen Saa'd said

```
_settings = (GUI_Settings)ObjectSerializing
    .DeserializeFromFile<GUI_Settings>("Settings.data");
```

When the code runs I need to send it a reference to _backend type backEndInitializer. This reference is held within this main class. GUI_Settings is the type that I am deserializing. _backend is the reference that I need to send the GUI_Settings() method to use.

---

**Answer:**

```
public static object DeSerializeObject(string filename, backEndInitializer backend)
    {
    object state = backend; // your object

    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bFormatter =
        new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(
            null,
            new System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(
                System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.All,
                state)); // pass it in

    object objectToSerialize;
    Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
    //BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    objectToSerialize = (object)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return objectToSerialize;
}
```

Then in the class that is being deserialized

```
public GUI_Settings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
            _backend = (backEndInitializer) ctxt.Context;
}
```

Comment: To achieve what? Your code passes in an object.

Comment: Well, when the I deseriaize the object I need to do some stuff when deserializer runs the GUI_Settings() method. But without the someObject reference I can't access what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        object state = null; // your object

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = 
            new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(
                null, 
                new System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(
                    System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.All, 
                    state)); // pass it in
```

From there you can access it object in the context argument in your deserialization constructor. The `StreamingContext` will have a reference to this instance

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers it finally helped me get it right. I'll post what I did above.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics to pass the type of the object that will be deserialized:

```
public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string fileName) where T : class
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Thing deserialized = DeserializeFromFile<Thing>(filePath);
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding where the object I am passing in to the GUI_Settings() method goes in this code?

Comment: Sorry, I am quit not understand what you want to achieve. However I feel like your problem can solved with use of `out` keyword..